# Linear independence & Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $y_1(t) = t^2$, $y_2(t) = t$ such that $t \in \mathbb{R}$ are solutions to the homogeneous equation $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$.

It is easy to show that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent in the open interval $I=(-1,1)$. Also, note that the Wronskian of these two functions is $W[y_1,y_2]\neq0$. However, if $t=0$ then $W[y_1,y_2](0)=0$.

---

**Question:** Is this somehow a contradiction to the claim "Two solutions of the homogeneous equation $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$ are linearly independent in the open interval $I$ if and only if $W[y_1,y_2]\neq0$"?

---

**Initial thoughts:** It is not because the one thing equals zero is the Wroskian evaluated at $t=0$ but not the Wronskian as such. Or, would it mean that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent in $I\backslash\{0\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no contradiction. If $t^2$ and $t$ are solutions then
solving for $p$ and $q$ you get $p=-2/t$ and $q=2/t^2$ which become singular when $t=0$. Then $W'=-pW=2W/t$ yields $W=ct^2$ in accordance with definitions.